# Coverlet won't break CircleCI

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, circleci

I have an open source project where I'm trying to learn about circleci. I want to make my CI break on branches when code coverage is bellow a threshold. Currently I'm using coverlet for this objective, the problem is that even thought the coverage is bellow the threshold and the prompt on CI says that there's an error, CI won't break and thus calling it a  success.

The source to my [yml circleci file](https://github.com/cecosmos/ProtoStar.Core/blob/dev/.circleci/config.yml).

Resulting on the following.

[image: circleci prompt errors]

Is there any way to ensure circleci breaks when the threshold is not reached?

Comment: *Adding this answer for information purpose and I don't have enough reputation to add it as comment.* Since you are using coverlet as nuget package in the project, above answer by @dnephin is only workaround as of now unfortunately, "Read contents of the output in your CI script and take action based on it". Because, Coverlet don't have control over returning exit codes when its used as nuget package reference since process is hosted by "dotnet test" not by "Coverlet". This exact issue was discussed here, [Coverlet Github Issue](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet/issues/388) and you will find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job success or failure is communicated to CircleCI by the exit code of the process. It sounds like the process you are running is exiting with code 0, which is why the job is successful.

Maybe `dotnet test` has a flag to exit non-zero if coverage is too low? If not might need to send the output to a file with `| tee filename` and write a script to read the file and exit non-zero when you want to fail the job.

Comment: Indeed I checked the return value ant it's 0.
I'm sure the reading the file is a way to go, but I'll try find other workaround though, since parsing the output seems a little dirty to me.

Comment: I hope there is a better way!